# align ancor in form using twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and I have a form with link that should open a popup with inputs.
For some reason the link is not vertically aligned. I would like to know what is the "bootstrap way" to do an anchor in a form. Here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3j7QP/4/
Here is the html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="postForm">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="start_location">Origin</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <a id="start_location" name="start_location" href="javascript:;">open select tooltip</a>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3j7QP/6/), you should use the `.help-inline` class (or `.help-block` depending on your needs) BUT even with that class you will need to tweak things if you don't put any inputs.

```html
<div class="controls noinput">
    <span class="help-inline"><!-- <a> --></span>
</div>
```

```css
.controls.noinput > .help-inline { line-height: 28px; }
```

The `28px` value may vary depending on your bootstrap variables. It basically equals the `control-group` height.